# imageview with zoom and scroll not working with UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am trying to put image in imageview with zoom and scroll. but when I set contentmode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill image get fix and zoom and scroll available.Any reason I am getting this behavior? below is code

```
 UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"b3.jpg" ofType:nil]];

        iScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [iScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

        iScrollView.delegate = self;
        // Disabling panning/scrolling in the scrollView
        iScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

        iImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        iImgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        [iScrollView addSubview:iImgView];
        [self addSubview:iScrollView];


- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return iImgView;
}
```

Comment: where adding yor imageView onto scrollview..?

Comment: yes adding imageview in scrollview and scrollview on main view.

Comment: sir check your code where is this line [iScrollView addsubview:imageview]

Comment: i think content size property you did not gave for UIScrollview and also adding subview.

Comment: @NitinGohel : sorry it was print mistake. have updated code.  [iScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(iImgView.frame.size.width, iImgView.frame.size.height)];

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by setting

```
 iImgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```